# ASP.NET 3.5 : Allow tilde(~) in URL with the help of regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a text box where I enter the URL. there is also validator set for the text box to check if the URL entered in textbox is valid.

I have used

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valTargetFormatUrl" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTargetUrl" ValidationExpression="(http|https)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

The above checks for valid URL that does not have special characters in it (like ~,%). I need a Expression to match '~'.

Example: I need an expression to make ( http://www.domainname.com/~/xyz.pdf ) as valid.

Comment: You have used _nothing_ for matching valid urls?

Comment: validationexpression attribute is used

Answer (score 1):

```
(http|https)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=~]*)?
```

sorry mistake on my part forgot to add ~ in the expression